# iOS: custom font for specific label

Tags: ios, fonts, objective-c++

I looked at a few examples here on OS and also followed [this one](http://kgriff.posterous.com/45359635) but what I wanted to know is how I can set a custom font for only one specific label.

This line is supposed to change the font:

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Cloister Black" size:64.0]
```

But I don't want everything to be affected. Any ideas how I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the font on a label is as easy as modifying that label's ["`font`" property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/font) (and I've linked Apple's documentation for you).

E.G.:

```
labelIWantToModify.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Cloister Black" size:64.0];
```

And I'm hoping you're referring to that one specific label, and not a piece or part of the string that appears within the label, which is a separate (attributed string) thing.